# macOS 13.2.1 M2 processor brew install openssl error

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, apple-silicon, macos-ventura

I'm trying to install `openssl@1.1` via `brew`, and it's failing during the `make` step.

OS

- macOS Venture 13.2.1
- Apple M2 Max

```
Darwin mbp 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Mon Jan 30 20:39:46 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020 arm64
```

Brew

```
Homebrew 4.0.3-140-gba8fd26
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 955021b2c36; last commit 2023-02-24)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 080a0c1e1c; last commit 2023-02-24)
```

Issue when running `brew install openssl@1.1` or any formulae that depends on `openssl@1.1` such as `openjdk` or `gradle`:

```
==> Fetching openssl@1.1
Warning: Building openssl@1.1 from source as the bottle needs:
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /opt/homebrew/Cellar (yours is /Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar)
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew (yours is /Users/someuser/homebrew)
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/someuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ec3feb171aa63b32c30a6e7423e78f743f92d1ef984b66b0ea548d08220c0ce6--openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t --openssldir=/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1 no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method no-zlib darwin64-arm64-cc enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/someuser/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl@1.1/02.make:
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.d.tmp -MT crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.o -c -o crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.o crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.d.tmp -MT crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.o -c -o crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.o crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rsa/rsa_prn.d.tmp -MT crypto/rsa/rsa_prn.o -c -o crypto/rsa/rsa_prn.o crypto/rsa/rsa_prn.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.d.tmp -MT crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.o -c -o crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.o crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rsa/rsa_saos.d.tmp -MT crypto/rsa/rsa_saos.o -c -o crypto/rsa/rsa_saos.o crypto/rsa/rsa_saos.c
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/rsa_none.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/rsa_lib.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** Deleting file `crypto/rsa/rsa_lib.o'
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/rsa_pss.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** Deleting file `crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.o'
/bin/sh: line 1: 66575 Killed: 9               cmp crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.d.tmp crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.d > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!

These open issues may also help:
openssl@1.1: make keg_only on Linux https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/119967
```

`brew config`:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.0.3
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: ba6d87eed9ce31f42fa2b33a4e6067d9cf17f13f
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap origin: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: c199be743a4e2870c855aa8948a1dc16bebb5c12
Core tap last commit: 65 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /Users/someuser/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /Users/someuser/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /Users/someuser/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 12
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit arm_blizzard_avalanche
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400
Git: 2.37.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.86.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 13.2.1-arm64
CLT: 14.2.0.0.1.1668646533
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

`brew doctor`:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew.

Many of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default prefix.
Consider uninstalling Homebrew and reinstalling into the default prefix.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this unsupported configuration.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
```

I also asked this question https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20372 to the `openssl` community, and it seems to be a problem with the `brew` unsupported installation approach.

Thanks for any help in advance!

UPDATE:

This was an issue with the user setup process on a company-provided Mac. I'm now able to install `openssl`.

Comment: Can you run `brew config` and `brew doctor` and dump the output to the OP? Thanks!

Comment: @chenrui, I have added the additional information requested. Thank you for looking at it!

Comment: Run `sudo sysctl security.mac.amfi.verbose_logging=1` followed by `log stream --process 0 --level debug --predicate 'sender == "AppleMobileFileIntegrity"'` and leave that running while you try to run the installation again, and see if anything shows up in the log stream.

Comment: Maybe try to fix `Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew`

Comment: @Siguza, I tried increasing the log level as you suggested. All messages look like this: `...kernel: (AppleMobileFileIntegrity) macOSTaskPolicy: (com.apple.sysmond) is allowed to get the task read port of...`. Were you expecting to see some error or exception being thrown here?

Comment: @rodrigo yes, I was expecting to see it kill processes for some sort of policy violation. But it seems that isn't the issue here then.